# Map not getting populated

Tags: soql, map, null-pointer, null

I have below code where the Map is not getting populated and throws Null Pointer error.

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

**Code:**

```
for(Business_Plan_abv__c obj : [select Id,Account_abv__c,Territory_abv__c,First_Name_abv__c,Last_Name_abv__c from Business_Plan_abv__c where Territory_abv__c=:terr]) {
    if(!accMap.containsKey(obj.Territory_abv__c)){
         accMap.put(obj.Territory_abv__c, new List<Business_Plan_abv__c>{obj});

    }else{
         accMap.get(obj.Territory_abv__c).add(obj);
    }

    system.debug('accmap@@@'+accMap);
}
```

Error throws elsewhere when i try getting the map values as below.

```
for(Business_Plan_abv__c j: accMap.get(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c))
{.......
}
```

The map is as below.

```
 Public Map<String, List<Business_Plan_abv__c>> accMap = new Map<String, List<Business_Plan_abv__c>>();
```

Comment: Please specify the Map type.

Comment: Public Map<String, List<Business_Plan_abv__c>> accMap = new Map<String, List<Business_Plan_abv__c>>();

Comment: select Id,Account_abv__c,Territory_abv__c,First_Name_abv__c,Last_Name_abv__c from Business_Plan_abv__c where Territory_abv__c=:terr  Does it have values

Answer (score 1):

Try to populate the map in this way:

**Code:**

```
for(Business_Plan_abv__c obj : [select Id,Account_abv__c,Territory_abv__c,First_Name_abv__c,Last_Name_abv__c from Business_Plan_abv__c where Territory_abv__c=:terr]) {
    if(!accMap.containsKey(obj.Territory_abv__c)){
         accMap.put(obj.Territory_abv__c, new List<Business_Plan_abv__c>{obj});

    }else{
         List<Business_Plan_abv__c> tempList = accMap.get(obj.Territory_abv__c)
         tempList.add(obj);
         accMap.put(obj.Territory_abv__c, tempList);
    }

    system.debug('accmap@@@'+accMap);
}
```

If the key is not present in the Map, then get() ,ethod returns null. Here `accMap.get(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c)` will return null if the key is does not exist and you are trying to iterate over a null value.

Add a null check. Try this.

```
if(accMap.get(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c) != null && accMap.get(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c).size() > 0){
    for(Business_Plan_abv__c j: accMap.get(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c))
    {
     .......
    }
}
```

Comment: But here the problem is accMap itself is not at all getting populated although BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c  === has value

Comment: Do check your SQOL because `Territory_abv__c` is a String and in your query you have where clause as `Territory_abv__c=:terr` which means you are doing case sensitive check

Answer (score 0):

Added to Ankita. IT's googd to check with [containksKey()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)

```
if(accMap.ContainsKey(BpToInsert[i].Territory_Name__c){
  //   Your for loop
}
```